# batch import query in MySql - joomla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, import

I have a folder containing 100+ .txt files witch I want to import each in one article (so to end up with 100+ articles) in my joomla website

It seems that the easiest way is to import my .txt in my existing mysql using something like :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE example_table
```

But how can I import all my files at once (batch import)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this macro (in visual basic) to import all the .txt into an excel worksheet :

```
'~~> Change path here
Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\file\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim MyData As String, tmpData() As String, strData() As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Your requirement is of 267 files of 1 line each but I created 
    '~~> an array big enough to to handle 1000 files
    Dim ResultArray(1000, 3) As String

    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Debug.Print "Process Started At : " & Now

    n = 1

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    strFileName = Dir(sPath & "\*.txt")

    '~~> Loop through folder to get the text files
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0

        '~~> open the file in one go and read it into an array
        Open sPath & "\" & strFileName For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        '~~> Collect the info in result array
        For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
            If Len(Trim(strData(i))) <> 0 Then
                tmpData = Split(strData(i), ",")

                ResultArray(n, 0) = Replace(tmpData(0), Chr(34), "")
                ResultArray(n, 1) = Replace(tmpData(1), Chr(34), "")
                ResultArray(n, 2) = Replace(tmpData(2), Chr(34), "")
                ResultArray(n, 3) = Replace(tmpData(3), Chr(34), "")

                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Get next file
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

    '~~> Write the array to the Excel Sheet
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ResultArray), _
    UBound(Application.Transpose(ResultArray))) = ResultArray

    Debug.Print "Process ended At : " & Now
End Sub
```

So now each line corresponds to one of the.txt.

Organize the columns like one in the table you want to import the .txt into. 
For example, if you want to import articles in joomla, you're columns should be: 
id title alias title_alias introtext fulltext state sectionid mask catid created created_by created_by_alias modified modified_by checked_out checked_out_time publish_up publish_down images urls attribs version parentid ordering metakey metadesc access hits metadata

Leave the id field empty if you want mysql to increment the id automatically during the upload.

Save your table as a .csv and import it in mysql with phpmyadmin (select the table you want to import you .csv and then select the import tab.

!! If you have western characters in your content (like é,à...) save the table as a .xlsm. Then open it in Open Office Calc and then save it as .csv.  In the pop up select, keep same format then western characters.

You're done!